# Scala - error when passing parameters

Tags: scala

I am doing the Martin Odersky course about Scala.
In one of the assignments I have the following type:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
```

I have defined a method which subtracts an element of type `(Char, Int)` from an element of type `Occurrences`.

```
  def subtractOne(x: Occurrences, (char: Char, nr: Int)): Occurrences = x match {
    case List() => throw new Exception("can not subtract")
    case (char, nr2) :: ocs => {
      if(nr2 > nr) (char, nr2 - nr) :: ocs
      else if(nr2 == nr) ocs
      else throw new Exception("can not subtract")
    }
    case _ :: ocs => subtractOne(ocs, (char, nr))
  }
```

However, I am getting some unclear errors on the first line: `Wrong parameter` and `Definition or declaration expected`.

Is there anything wrong with the way I declared the parameters?

Comment: You cannot "pattern match" a tuple in the parameter list of a method. Use `def subtractOne(x: Occurrences, e: (Char,Int)): Occurrences` then refer your tuple elements via `e._1` and `e._2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use brackets in parameter list. Unless you want to define tuple but it should be done with one name.

`def subtractOne(x: Occurrences, char: Char, nr: Int): Occurrences = x match {`

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are defined under one name - charAndNr: (Char, Int)
Also Nil is preferred to List()